# How to make image more contrast, grayscale then get all characters exactly with PIL and pytesseract?

Tags: python-3.x, python-tesseract

PLease download the attatchment here and save it as `/tmp/target.jpg`.

[image]
You can see that there are `0244R` in the jpg,i extract string with below python code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import cv2
filename = "/tmp/target.jpg"
image = cv2.imread(filename)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,55, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold))
```

What I get is

```
0244K
```

The right string is  `0244R`,how to  make image more contrast, grayscale then get all characters exactly with with PIL and pytesseract?
Here is the webpage which generate the image :

http://www.crup.cn/ValidateCode/Index?t=0.14978241776661583

Comment: Risks are that people will provide a solution that only works on this image. Do you have the code that generates this image ?

Comment: You were shown the process required to perform this type of cleaning the last time you asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57183997/why-cant-get-string-with-pil-and-pytesseract.  It's not a perfect process.

Comment: @potential answerers, this is a robot validation for account creation and login at China Renmin University Press http://www.crup.cn/Account/Login  I cannot know what the OP intends to use this for, but if you are in China, aiding the OP in circumventing this may not be kosher.

Comment: @Scott That's a good FYI!

Comment: Everyday i login into the website to get points by hand ,i am tired of that action,i want to write a program to login and get points for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply `adaptive-thresholding` and `bitwise-not` operations to the input image, the result will be:

[image]

Now if you remove the special characters like (dot, comma, etc..)

```py
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bnt, config="--psm 6")
res = ''.join(i for i in txt if i.isalnum())
print(res)
```

Result will be:

```py
O244R
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("Aw6sN.jpg")
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thr = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gry, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                            cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 23, 100)
bnt = cv2.bitwise_not(thr)
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(bnt, config="--psm 6")
res = ''.join(i for i in txt if i.isalnum())
print(res)
```